# Send commands to an application via command-line

Tags: linux, qt

I have access to a Linux-based machine via command-line and I would like to modify a QT application that I'm supposed to run such that I can send it commands via the terminal. This is supposed to serve as an alternative in case the GUI is unavailable so that I can simulate, say a button press, with a command from the CLI. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Answers would be completely different for large and small projects.

Comment: AND, you're basically seeking a recomendation. That is off topic here. Show your best attempt at coding a solution and readers may help you fix it. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ,   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ,  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good Luck

Comment: @shellter I understand, but I can't code something if I don't even know what approach to take... The only thing I have come across so far is using some utility like `nc` to send commands to the application and have a listener socket in the application to process them. But I'd like to know if there might be a better way.

Comment: Make a new question and show your current work. Include a small set of inputs, the required output, your currrent output, any error messages AND if possible include some sort of metrics for your currrent test. Something someone can copy/paste into their own enviroment and see the issue. Then readers will have something to "bounce off of" and very likely show you if there is a better way . Avoid verbal descrriptions! Show actual code/facts! Put a comment below the new Q with my userID and I'll look at it. (Think how to address Stark's comment above). . Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, re-read your qusetion and as Stark says, its completely different for small vs large application. That you are having to ask how to modify a QT application indicates you've never done GUI coding (correct?)  and likely haven't done any C/C++/Java coding? (correct?) . What is your experience then? In any case, if you're going to continue, you'll need to illustrate your problem visually, and add verbal comments. Find 1 simple task in the real app you need to work on and give details of how that should work. Readers want to work on something specific. Good luck.

Comment: And are you sure your QT app doesn't have a mechanism built in that can take CLI commands while running? (look for a man page and possibly an info page). Also .... How many apps, are they custom built, or typical package open-source apps. With very few exceptions, you're looking at building your own version of these programs (editing existing code, adding new functions, testing, etc). OK. Today's first comment still has some validity but don't get freaked out on my "sample inputs, etc" (usual adivce). Busy now, will check back later. Good luck.